# my opencart website admin panel is not working

Tags: php, opencart

My wesbite is working fine but I can't seem to open my admin area.

http://www.haratistore.com/admin/

could please suggest me good solution

**my  opencart  Version  is 1.5.3.1**

Comment: As i can see, u migrated your site from http://www.ore.com/ to this one or some how your site is getting css, js from there. U can see this in console, just correct you admin > config.php path and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it your config.php file in the **/admin/** folder is not set properly.

Your site is trying to pull data from **www.ore.com**

Would be more helpful if you post your **config.php** file so that we can see what the issue is.

**NOTE:**

**Do not post the database,user,password from the config.php**

Answer (score 0):

// HTTP

1. define('HTTP_SERVER', 'Your Website URL/admin/');
2. define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'Your Website URL/');

**// HTTPS**

3. define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'Your Website URL/admin/');
4. define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'Your Website URL/');

**// DIR**

5. define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/Your Directory Name/public_html/admin/');
6. define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/Your Directory Name/public_html/system/');
7. define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/Your Directory Name/public_html/image/');
8. define('DIR_LANGUAGE','/home/YourDirectoryName/public_html/admin/language/');
9. define('DIR_TEMPLATE','/home/YourDirectoryName/public_html/admin/view/template/');
10. define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/Your Directory Name/public_html/system/config/');
11. define('DIR_CACHE','/home/YourDirectoryName/public_html/system/storage/cache/');
12. define('DIR_DOWNLOAD','/home/YourDirectoryName/public_html/system/storage/download/');
13. define('DIR_LOGS','/home/YourDirectoryName/public_html/system/storage/logs/');
14. define('DIR_MODIFICATION','/home/YourDirectoryName/public_html/system/storage/modification/');
15. define('DIR_UPLOAD','/home/YourDirectoryName/public_html/system/storage/upload/');
16. define('DIR_CATALOG','/home/Your Directory Name/public_html/catalog/');

**// DB**

17. define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
18. define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
19. define('DB_USERNAME', 'Your Database User Name');
20. define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Your Database Password');
21. define('DB_DATABASE', 'Your Database Name');
22. define('DB_PORT', '3306');
23. define('DB_PREFIX', 'your table Prefix Check');

Comment: yes   it working But when i try to login (No match for Username and/or Password.)   and do not response...  could you please tell me haw to fix ..

Comment: also not working my home page http://haratistore.com/   after ading to card when i clik check out every thing erase from my list